# What was varna of foot soldiers of Mahabharata war?

Tags: mahabharata, caste-system, kshatriya, war

Tens/hundreds of thousands of foot soldiers supposed to have participated in Mahabharata war. Usually in historical pre-modern wars of such magnitudes we see foot soldiers being conscripted from ordinary peasantry, they are not professional soldiers. My question is do any of the scriptures mention varna of these foot soldiers? Were they all kshatriyas, part of standing armies of various kingdoms or were they vaishya/sudras temporarily taking up arms and following their kshatriya "officers"?

Comment: It should be mix of "Kshatriya"-s and "Shudra"-s. "Shudra" is defined as a category, which serves in all the fields. A "Shudra" who becomes "Dvija" (2nd born after training/learning) in the field of martial arts, sports etc., would become "Kshatriya".

Comment: Some of them were from Krishna's Narayani sena of Yadavas , so mostly of "Kshatriya" as said by @iammilind