# What was the Varna of the so many soldiers of the various kingdoms mentioned in the stories of Puranas and Vedas?

Tags: vedas, puranas, caste-system, varna, kshatriya

There are so many kingdoms and wars mentioned in the stories in [Puranas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puranas) and [Vedas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedas). In all stories King used to be `Kshatriya`.

I never read and heard about Varna of soldiers who were in huge number in any kingdom.

Were all those soldiers `Kshatriya`?

Comment: Related (no answer): [Varna of Foot Soldiers of Mahabharata War](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19642/what-was-varna-of-foot-soldiers-of-mahabharata-war) Some of the kings in the Puranas are also in the Mahabharata.